# Apache Ignite Spark Integration persists data to Ignite error

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I want to persist the DataFrame data to the ignite table, and native debugging is normal. When running on spark on yarn, it always reports an error.

```
   df.write
      .format(IgniteDataFrameSettings.FORMAT_IGNITE)
      .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CONFIG_FILE, "META-INF/default-config.xml")
      .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_STREAMER_ALLOW_OVERWRITE, true)
      .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS, "primary_key")
      .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_STREAMER_FLUSH_FREQUENCY, 10000)
      .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_TABLE, "tb_name")
      .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PARAMETERS, "template=partitioned,backups=0,affinityKey=groupcode")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .save()
```

This is spark config

```
/data/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit\
 --queue default\
 --class cn.com.DataProcess\
 --name DataProcess\
 --master yarn\
 --deploy-mode client \
 --conf spark.default.parallelism=20\
 --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/data/ignite/*\
 --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/data/ignite/*\
 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=utf8\
 --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=utf8\
 --num-executors 6\
 --executor-memory 1G\
 --total-executor-cores 6\
 --jars /data/ignite/service-2.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /data/ignite/service-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Error stack:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 451, hadoop-slave2, executor 4): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.QueryHelper$.org$apache$ignite$spark$impl$QueryHelper$$savePartition(QueryHelper.scala:155)
    at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.QueryHelper$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(QueryHelper.scala:117)
    at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.QueryHelper$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(QueryHelper.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Which friend has encountered this problem, please help me！**

I found the source code based on the error message and judged that it should be the error suggested here。

```
private def savePartition(iterator: Iterator[Row],
        insertQry: String,
        tblName: String,
        ctx: IgniteContext,
        streamerAllowOverwrite: Option[Boolean],
        streamerFlushFrequency: Option[Long],
        streamerPerNodeBufferSize: Option[Int],
        streamerPerNodeParallelOperations: Option[Int]
    ): Unit = {
        **val tblInfo = sqlTableInfo[Any, Any](ctx.ignite(), tblName).get**

        val streamer = ctx.ignite().dataStreamer(tblInfo._1.getName)     

    }
```

But I don't understand why this happens. Both cache name and table name exist. Is my code used incorrectly?

Comment: If you create the table with CREATE TABLE command then try to set the cache name to the table’s name with CACHE_NAME parameter passing it to the WITH clause: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/sql-reference/ddl

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but it will still report the same error.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem has been solved, I can delete the original data table.